# when key in obj transcompiled into usage of __indexOf with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This teaspoon of Coffee ...

```
    _pickInConf = (sourceConf,propsToPick...) ->
      newConfWithPickedProperties = {}
      newConfWithPickedProperties[key] = sourceConf[key] for key in Array::.concat.apply Array::,propsToPick when key in sourceConf
      newConfWithPickedProperties
```

... gets compiled into :

```
_pickInConf = function() {
  var key, newConfWithPickedProperties, propsToPick, sourceConf, _i, _len, _ref;
  sourceConf = arguments[0], propsToPick = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
  newConfWithPickedProperties = {};
  _ref = Array.prototype.concat.apply(Array.prototype, propsToPick);
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    key = _ref[_i];
    if (__indexOf.call(sourceConf, key) >= 0) {
      newConfWithPickedProperties[key] = sourceConf[key];
    }
  }
  return newConfWithPickedProperties;
};
```

... and makes use of :

```
__indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };
```

I expected Coffeescript compiler to transcompile this chunk :

```
when key in sourceConf
```

into :

```
if (key in sourceConf) {
```

... Which is what i meant to code in JS ...

Is there a way i can force Coffescript to output this kind of JS ? Or to make it understand that sourceConf is an object, not an array ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: What did you want ur whole chunk to be compiled to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `of` not `in` to iterate keys of an object: http://coffeescript.org/#loops (near the end of the section)

To expand on this:

```
for a in items when a of obj
  stuff
```

compiles to

```
var a, _i, _len;

for (_i = 0, _len = items.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  a = items[_i];
  if (a in obj) {
    stuff;

  }
}
```

which is using the `a in obj` you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Jim !I just figured it out using js2coffe !

Answer (score 0):

You want `of`, not `in` to check for the occurence of a key: http://coffeescript.org/#operators